# sbt sometimes takes long to compile (super long..)

Tags: scala, playframework, sbt, slick

Currently I'm running a fairly middle-sized project with the Play Framework and sbt/scala. However, sometimes it takes long time to compile the project, like 4 classes taking something like 120 seconds, while most of the time the project takes just a bunch of seconds for everything!
However mostly it looks that it takes a while longer for a bunch of files when refactoring some things inside my Database Access and Services, while creating private / public functions of slick code without return codes.

Still is there anything to do against this ?

It just looks like sbt is hanging while doing:

```
[info] Loading project definition from /Users/schmitch/projects/envisia/envisia-erp-loki/project
[info] Set current project to envisia-erp-loki (in build file:/Users/schmitch/projects/envisia/envisia-erp-loki/)
[info] Compiling 4 Scala sources to /Users/schmitch/projects/envisia/envisia-erp-loki/modules/utils/target/scala-2.11/classes...
```

while utils is a sbt subproject. Any idea's why it takes so long? and mostly while that only happens sometimes?

Here is my sbt file:

```
name := "envisia-erp-loki"

version := "1.0.1-SNAPSHOT"

lazy val utils = project in file("modules/utils")

lazy val migrator = (project in file("modules/migrator"))
  .enablePlugins(PlayScala).disablePlugins(PlayLayoutPlugin)
  .dependsOn(utils).aggregate(utils)

lazy val codegen = (project in file("modules/codegen"))
  .dependsOn(utils).aggregate(utils)

lazy val auth = (project in file("modules/auth"))
  .enablePlugins(PlayScala).disablePlugins(PlayLayoutPlugin)
  .dependsOn(utils).aggregate(utils)

lazy val pdfgen = project in file("modules/pdfgen")

lazy val root = (project in file("."))
  .enablePlugins(PlayScala, DebianPlugin)
  .dependsOn(utils).aggregate(utils)
  .dependsOn(auth).aggregate(auth)
  .dependsOn(pdfgen).aggregate(pdfgen)

scalaVersion in ThisBuild := "2.11.6"


libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  filters,
  cache,
  ws,
  specs2 % Test,
  "com.typesafe.play" %% "play-slick" % "1.0.0",
  "com.typesafe.play" %% "play-slick-evolutions" % "1.0.0",
  "com.typesafe.play" %% "play-mailer" % "3.0.1",
  "org.elasticsearch" % "elasticsearch" % "1.5.2",
  "org.postgresql" % "postgresql" % "9.4-1201-jdbc41",
  "com.chuusai" %% "shapeless" % "2.2.0",
  "com.nulab-inc" %% "play2-oauth2-provider" % "0.15.0",
  "io.github.nremond" %% "pbkdf2-scala" % "0.4",
  "com.google.code.findbugs" % "jsr305" % "3.0.0"
)


resolvers += "scalaz-bintray" at "http://dl.bintray.com/scalaz/releases"


resolvers ++= Seq(
  Resolver.sonatypeRepo("releases"),
  Resolver.sonatypeRepo("snapshots")
)

// Faster compilations:
sources in(Compile, doc) := Seq.empty

publishArtifact in(Compile, packageDoc) := false

// "com.googlecode.java-diff-utils" % "diffutils" % "1.3.0"

//pipelineStages := Seq(rjs)

// Play provides two styles of routers, one expects its actions to be injected, the
// other, legacy style, accesses its actions statically.
routesGenerator := InjectedRoutesGenerator

JsEngineKeys.engineType := JsEngineKeys.EngineType.Node


// Do not add API Doc
sources in(Compile, doc) := Seq.empty

publishArtifact in(Compile, packageDoc) := false

// RpmPlugin
maintainer in Linux := "Christian Schmitt <c.schmitt@envisia.de>"

packageSummary in Linux := "Envisia ERP Server 3.0"

packageDescription := "This is the new Envisia ERP Server it will be as standalone as possible"

import com.typesafe.sbt.packager.archetypes.ServerLoader.Systemd

serverLoading in Debian := Systemd


scalacOptions in ThisBuild ++= Seq(
  "-target:jvm-1.8",
  "-encoding", "UTF-8",
  "-deprecation", // warning and location for usages of deprecated APIs
  "-feature", // warning and location for usages of features that should be imported explicitly
  "-unchecked", // additional warnings where generated code depends on assumptions
  "-Xlint", // recommended additional warnings
  "-Ywarn-adapted-args", // Warn if an argument list is modified to match the receiver
  "-Ywarn-value-discard", // Warn when non-Unit expression results are unused
  "-Ywarn-inaccessible",
  "-Ywarn-dead-code"
)

updateOptions in ThisBuild := updateOptions.value.withCachedResolution(true)
```

Comment: can you show us your sbt file? are there any dependencies?

Comment: I have similar problem lastly, but running sbt clean before actual build task fixes the problem. If you're running Intellij you can simply add it to run config,

Comment: @Peanut I added my sbt, however mostly it hangs on utils, while the other projects are just running fine. In utils I manually insert Database table files that are generated with slick-codegen, it's a big file with something like 6k loc. However even when not updating it, and just updating the database driver which is the Tables file uses it will take long, mostly while changing the Tables file itself it is really really fast (less than seconds) and sbt clean doesn't help that often.

Comment: @Haito What about in-time compilation while coding, not full build, that OP was speaking of at the end of the question?